# AWS IAM terms mapping document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm reading a document with references like this:

```
Select the checkbox next to the “AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess” policy (recommended) and click “Next Step”.
If a custom policy is created, “DescribeRegions” and “DescribeInstances” permissions are required.
```

and am trying to express that in a Policy like this:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
         "ec2:DescribeInstances", "ec2:DescribeImages",
         "ec2:DescribeTags", "ec2:DescribeSnapshots"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
   }
   ]
}
```

but I can't how you would break the `AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess` policy down into the `ec2:*` format.

I've looked here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation-guide&searchQuery=AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess&x=0&y=0&this_doc_product=AWS+Command+Line+Interface&this_doc_guide=User+Guide&doc_locale=en_us#facet_doc_product=AWS%20Command%20Line%20Interface&facet_doc_guide=User%20Guide

and the 825 page PDF on EC2 here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ec2-clt.pdf

Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the AWS console, navigate to IAM and then Policies. Search for the policy of interest and click it. That will take you to a page that describes the policy and provides the equivalent JSON.

The equivalent JSON policy for [AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess$serviceLevelSummary) appears to be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that this policy may change over time as new features/services are added. That's a good reason to consider using the managed AWS policies over your own equivalents.

Comment: Good point re policy change. What's the Action for AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes. Given the comment about policy change how do you describe a JSON policy for AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess (without breaking it down into permissions)?

Comment: You can't, and you don't need to. AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess is an AWS-managed policy. You create an IAM role (or group or user) and you attach the AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess policy to it.